# How to make easy to share offline django projects

Tags: python, django, deployment, server, offline

I have completed a Django project. It runs well on the development server on my machine. However, it can't be shared and run on other devices easily. *How can I package it so that it can easily be shared and run on local server, offline on individual machines?*

**What I do**: I use xampp to serve it from Apache then manually copy the necessary files. However this has too many setting up steps, copy paste files and not user friendly at all. Is there a better way?

Comment: take a look to `docker` you can create a docker file and do the installation in there so people will need to pull your docker image and run it on their computer, pretty much out of the box experiecne

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.